# When trying to send a scroll event based off of a user's recorded actions, the distance scrolled is not the same as the user's

Tags: swift, macos, scroll

I'm trying to create an application in Swift 5 that captures all mouse and keyboard events (essentially a keylogger) and saves them into a .csv so it can later playback the events by reading that .csv. It also records a video for reference. This is for the purpose of quality/UI testing and to help capture exact workflows from different types of users. I've got clicks and keystrokes working, but I'm having some issues with scrolling. I try capturing the event.scrollingDeltaY and then creating a CGEvent to send it, but the result is very jumpy and doesn't match the scrolling the user did.

I've tried scrollingDeltaY and for the CGEvent unit I've tried both CGScrollEventUnit.pixel and CGScrollEventUnit.line, but both aren't behaving as I expect.

```swift
// Creating the string to add to the .csv during recording
tempStr += event.deltaX.description + "," + event.scrollingDeltaY.description + "\n"



// the CGEvent created during playback
let eventScroll = CGEvent(scrollWheelEvent2Source: nil, units: CGScrollEventUnit.pixel, wheelCount: 1, wheel1: Int32(deltaY), wheel2: 0, wheel3: 0)

eventScroll?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

I expect the app to scroll the same distance as the user did, however that is not the case here.

Comment: Are all `scrollWheelEvent…` fields of both `CGEvent`s the same?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, the solution seems to lie in the fact that `event.scrollingDeltaY` appears to be in lines not in pixels.

Try changing `CGScrollEventUnit.pixel` to `CGScrollEventUnit.line` (or just `.line`)